# Mysql Trigger - Update table when update another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have three tables:

**Import** Table:

```
import_id  | status
-------------------------
   1       |    1
   2       |    0
```

**ImportItem** Table:

```
import_id    |  product_id |  quantity_import
-------------------------------------
    2        |     1       |    5
    2        |     2       |    2
    2        |     3       |    10
```

**Product** Table:

```
product_id   |  quantity_1   |  quantity_2
------------------------------------------
    1        |     10        |     0
    2        |     5         |     0
    3        |     15        |     0
```

I want to create a trigger update `quantity_2` in **product table** when update `status` in **Import table**.

I want the same result:
 
When i update `status = 1` in **Import Table** , `quantity_2 = quantity_1 - quantity_import` and will update new quantity_1 and quantity_2

Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: Can't you just use a query for that? Triggers are kind of a last resort.

Comment: Do you have any solution to the problem? @juergen d

Comment: Yes, delete the `quantity2` column, and select that value on-the-fly in a query when you join `importitem` table

Comment: Can you add your expected outcome please.